# Fill form with values from database in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, axios

I am attempting to create an edit form in React. I can successfully query my database and can see the data is what is expected after my get request. I then want to set the state of various properties on my component so it fills in my form, which I can then edit.

Here is my react component

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            teamName: '',
            bio: '',
            teamId: '',
            uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
           this.findPlayerById(this.props.params.id)
    }

    findPlayerById(playerId) {
        axios.get("/api/player/" + playerId)
            .then(res => {
                const player = res.data;
                console.log(player);
                this.setState({
                    name: player.name,
                    teamName: player.teamName,
                    bio: player.bio,
                    teamId: player.teamId,
                    uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl: player.profileImageUrl
                });
            });
    }
```

And here is my rendered HTML

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label className="control-label">Name</label>
           <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="name"
                  defaultValue={this.state.name}
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}/>
</div>
```

I don't get any errors but I don't think the state is being correctly set within my promise. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It look like nothing wrong. You want mean you want input change when fetching success, right? if you need to change input value after fetching, you should use `value={this.state.name} instead of defaultValue={this.state.name}`

Comment: That worked, thanks